# In SwiftUI, is there a way to expand and contract a view to show hidden text and buttons in the expanded version of the view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, swiftui

I'm making a simple task app and using ForEach to populate task rows with the task information from my model. I need a way to animate my task view to open up and reveal some description text and two buttons. I want to turn from A into B on tap, and then back again on tap:

[Design Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyQFm.png)

I've tried a couple things. I successfully got a proof-of-concept rectangle animating in a test project, but there are issues. The rectangle shrinks and grows from the centre point, vs. from the bottom only. When I place text inside it, the text doesn't get hidden and it looks really bad.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var animate = false
var animation: Animation = .spring()

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 200, height: animate ? 60 : 300)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation(animation) {
                    animate.toggle()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

In my main app, I was able to replace my first task view (closed) with another view that's open. This works but it looks bad and it's not really doing what I want. It's effectively replacing the view with another one using a fade animation.

```
ForEach(taskArrayHigh) { task in
if animate == false {
    TaskView(taskTitle: task.title, category: task.category?.rawValue ?? "", complete: task.complete?.rawValue ?? "", priorityColor: Color("HighPriority"), task: task, activeDate: activeDate)
        .padding(.top, 10)
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.easeIn) {
                animate.toggle()
            }
        }
        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
} else if animate == true {
    TaskViewOpen(task: "Grocery Shopping", category: "Home", remaining: 204, completed: 4)
        .padding(.top, 10)
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.easeIn) {
                animate.toggle()
            }
        }
}
```

Is there a way to animate my original closed view to open up and reveal the description text and buttons?

Comment: Look at `DisclosureGroup`, it might be what you want.

Comment: @CenkBilgen Good idea. I looked into it and I don't think it's possible. You can only place a view inside the expanded label portion of the DisclosureGroup. In my case, I need my entire view to open up and reveal the text and buttons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are on the right track with your `.transition` line you have, but you want to make sure that the container stays the same and the contents change -- right now, you're replacing the entire view.

Here's a simple example illustrating the concept:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isExpanded = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Headline")
            if isExpanded {
                Text("More Info")
                Text("And more")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
        .background(Color.gray.cornerRadius(10.0))
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                isExpanded.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since you're using it inside a `ForEach`, you'll probably want to abstract this into its own component, as it'll need its own `@State` to keep track of the expanded state as I've shown here.

---

**Update, based on comments**:

Example of using a PreferenceKey to get the height of the expandable view so that the frame can be animated and nothing fades in and out:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isExpanded = false
    @State var subviewHeight : CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Headline")
            VStack {
                Text("More Info")
                Text("And more")
                Text("And more")
                Text("And more")
                Text("And more")
                Text("And more")
            }
        }
        .background(GeometryReader {
            Color.clear.preference(key: ViewHeightKey.self,
                                   value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height)
        })
        .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) { subviewHeight = $0 }
        .frame(height: isExpanded ? subviewHeight : 50, alignment: .top)
        .padding()
        .clipped()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
        .background(Color.gray.cornerRadius(10.0))
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 2.0)) {
                isExpanded.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ViewHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = value + nextValue()
    }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick! I totally didn't connect that I could show and hide specific content in the view. The only little issue is the text and buttons fade in, while the rectangle expands and contracts out. Is there any way to make the text and buttons also contract out like the rectangle?

Comment: Yes, but it starts getting more complicated. See my update for an example.

Comment: This is the exact effect I was looking for. I'll have to pour over your code.

Comment: I was about to combine two transitions using `.transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .top).combined(with: .opacity))
                        .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.25))`. Doesn't look as good but it's much easier :).

Comment: Is it only work on Stack? I tried using single text view but does not work. It can not get the necessary height in onPrefChanged

Comment: No, it is not dependent on `Stack`. It should work on any SwiftUI `View`. If you're having a problem implementing it, please start a new question and include the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Using Swift 5 you can use withAnimation and have the view hidden based on state.

#### ExpandViewer

- Has a button to show and hide the inner view
- Takes in a content view

```swift
struct ExpandViewer <Content: View>: View {
    
    @State private var isExpanded = false
    @ViewBuilder let expandableView : Content
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 0.5)) {
                    self.isExpanded.toggle()
                }
                
            }){
                Text(self.isExpanded ? "Hide" : "View")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 40, alignment: .center)
                    .background(.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(5.0)
            }
            
            if self.isExpanded {
                 self.expandableView
            }
            
        }
       
    }
}
```

#### Using the viewer

```swift
ExpandViewer {
  Text("Hidden Text")
  Text("Hidden Text")
}
```